# how to deserialize json to a dictionary or keyvaluepair?

Tags: java, json, network-programming

I have to deserialize a JSON object like this

```
[{"Key":{"id":0, "Name":"an Object"}, "Value":true},
{"Key":{"id":0, "Name":"an Object"}, "Value":true}]
```

I know how to deserialize arrays and singleobjects or variables. but I'm in the blue about dictionaries.

I'm using the following to read an array

```
NetworkEvent n = (NetworkEvent) evt;
byte[] data = (byte[]) n.getMetaData();

AnObject[] anObject= null;
 try {
     JSONArray json = new JSONArray(new String(data, "UTF-8"));
     anObject= AnObject.getAnObjects(json);
 } catch (Exception ex) {
     ex.printStackTrace();
 }
```

The final code solution:

```
        Object[] objects= new Object[json.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); ++i) {

            Key key= null;
            Value value = null;
            try {
                JSONObject keyValuePair = json.getJSONObject(i);
                key= Key.getKey(keyValuePair.getJSONObject("Key"));
                value= keyValuePair.getBoolean("Value");
            } catch (JSONException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

          Object object= new object();
          object.setKey(key);
          object.setValue(value);

          Objects[i] = object;
        }
        return objects;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have there is not a JSON object.  It is an array of JSON objects, and therefore your current code should work.

I think that your "problem" is that you are using the wrong terminology.

This is an attribute or name/value pair:

```
"id":0
```

This is an object:

```
{"id":0, "Name":"an Object"}
```

This is also an object:

```
{"Key":{"id":0, "Name":"an Object"}, "Value":true}
```

This is an array (of objects)

```
[{"Key":{"id":0, "Name":"an Object"}, "Value":true},
 {"Key":{"id":0, "Name":"an Object"}, "Value":true}]
```

For more details, refer to the [json.org site](http://json.org).

Answer (score -1):

Try the [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) library.

Comment: I'm using json.org --Changing libraries in this phase of the project is not an option. But it looks a great library